# Algorithm for counting occurrences in a linked list

Tags: algorithm, list

For an unordered linked-list, what algorithm would work to count the number of occurrences of a specific piece of data?

Comment: As linked-lists aren't native python datatypes, you must have implemented your own, which means we'd need to see how you did that.  Plus what you've tried to do to solve the problem.

Comment: It's called "brute-force search", also known as "loop" :-)

Comment: @Bergi Sure. That's a valid answer (which you can see I supplied below) to a valid (albeit simple) question.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Thanks, I know it was a simple question, I was just confused because in my lecture we had just learned about:

   `Class Node:
          def __init__(self,initdata):self.data = initdata

                               self.next = none

                   Class UnorderedList:

                          def __init__(self):

                                self.hed = None`

Comment: No worries - please make sure you upvote any answers that helped you, and accept the answer that is the "right" answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm (pseudo-code):

```
node = list.head
count = 0
while node: # while we have a valid node
   if node.data == target_data:
      count++
   node = node.next  # assume this returns a "false" value if there is no next node
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using a hash map mapping from element to the count. In pseudocode, it could look like this:

```
map = new HashMap()

for (item : list) {
  if map.has_key(item)
    ++map[item]
  else
    map[item] = 0
}
```

after that, for each item, map[item] contains the number of occurrences of item.

If you only want to count a specific item, you could also do it like this

```
count = 0
for (item : list) {
  if (item == counted_item) {
    ++count
  }
}
```

and then count contains the number of currences of counted_item.

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that the list type has an interator.  A "raw" linked list would not have that.   IE this answer does not address the "linked list" aspect of the question.